# How to filter record by custom value from any dimension in dc.js?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

How to remove custom records from any dimension. In the below case how do I filter only category 'S' and allow rest of them in dimension ?

Example

```
let data = [
{category:'A',value:10},
{category:'B',value:11},
{category:'S',value:12},
{category:'A',value:14},
{category:'B',value:12},
]

let ndx = crossfilter(data);

let dim= ndx.dimension(function(d){
    if(d.category != "S") return d.category;
})
```

This above code runs into loop and the application crashes. I don't want to create separate data for this dimension rather link it with other cross filters.

Comment: For completeness sake, the reason this crashes is that a dimension key function [must return a naturally ordered value](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#natural-ordering-of-dimension-and-group-values). Since this one returns `undefined` when the category is `S`, the resulting values can’t be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its pretty simple, I did little research after posting the question.

Just manipulate the group parameter being passed to the chart. The code goes something like this.

Since I am trying to remove the value by key lets first write a function for further uses as well.

```
function removeByKey(source_group, value) {
    return {
        all: function() {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.key != value;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Once this is done the place where you call the group method for the charts call this method. The first parameter of removeByKey method is the group itself the second is the key value which is supposed to be removed from the chart.

```
 chart
   .dimension(dimension_data)
   .group(removeByKey(dimension_data_group, 'S'))
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. Well said. For future readers, this technique of wrapping a group in an object that generates a different data set on demand is called “fake groups”; [more info here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups).

Comment: Is there any limitation on which type of group being uses ? Like groupAll vs group used for the fake groups ?

Comment: Yes. A groupAll is fundamentally a different type from a group. It has a method called `value` that returns a single value, whereas a group has a method called `all` which returns an array of `{key, value}` pairs. There are circumstances where it can be useful to adapt one into the other, but usually there are incompatible. Only the `dc.numberDisplay` is designed to work with a groupAll. But I’m not sure if I understand the intent behind your question.

Comment: Yes I was trying to use fake groups for number Display components its not working.

Comment: Yes you probably want a fake groupAll, that is, an object with a `value()` method, for a number display. If you pass in a group it will use the first item returned by `.all()`, which is not all that useful. A weird thing is that the value accessor still looks for `.value` even though a groupAll returns only a value not an object. That said, I don’t know what you’re trying to do, so please ask another question or take this to the users group (better place for open ended discussion), since it has nothing to do with this question. Thanks!

Comment: My question goes here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242279/how-to-create-fakegroup-equivalent-for-numberdisplay-in-dc-js